# Elm - list of random numbers without duplicates

Tags: random, elm

I am making a game in elm and trying to randomly place N evil robots on a grid with ROWS x COLS cells.

What I would like is a List (Int, Int) pairs that specifies where to place the N robots.

I can make a List of coordinate pairs with

```
makeGrid : Seed -> List (Int, Int)
makeGrid seed = 
  let gen = list n <| pair (int 0 rows) (int 0 cols)
in 
  fst (generate gen seed)
```

That's fine. But if I want to generate a list of **unique** pairs?

Should I do the imperative solution where I keep a Set of my things and 
loop through adding until I have enough?

Maybe something like this (probably wrong, didn't check it in the REPL):

```
makeN : Int -> Seed -> (List (Int, Int), Seed)
makeN n seed = 
  let gen = list n <| pair (int 0 rows) (int 0 cols)
in 
  generate gen seed

makeGrid : List(Int, Int) -> Seed -> Int -> List (Int, Int)
makeGrid partial seed n =
  case of List.length partial 
    n -> partial
    current -> 
      let (new_elems, new_seed) = makeN (n - current) seed
      makeGrid Set.toList (Set.fromList <| append partial new_elems) new_seed n
```

This feels off. I've thought of 3 alternatives:

1. Make my grid a list of ROWS * COLS coordinate pairs with type List (Int, Int), then shuffle it, and take the first N pairs in the list to place my robots on. This seems very concise and clean, but inefficient/bad if the number of unique points I need is much smaller than my grid, and if my grid is big (as Fisher-Yates is O(n log(n)) I think).
2. Use something like [this package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mgold/Elm-Random-Sampling/2.0.3/Random-Array) to sample from my grid without replacement, but I need to change my grid into an Array and it looks like it does a lot of splitting and splicing Array operations, which look costly.
3. Use the JS FFI to implement this in a 4 line JS loop.

None of these solutions feel good, is there something I'm missing?
I'm probably going to just change the game mechanics to that each cell has a probability P of having a robot on it, so that it's simpler to implement.

Comment: Right after posting this it appears to me that I should be able to use a special generator for this.
I'm looking at Random.Extra, the Set generator and some of the generateUntil family methods listed.

Comment: That sounds like the right approach. Be sure to add an answer to your question if you figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/NoRedInk/elm-random-extra/issues/3) on elm-random-extra, and [mgold](https://github.com/mgold) helped me develop a function similar to what is in the question, then added it to elm-random-extra 2.1.1. Thanks a lot mgold!

The function is `set` in elm-random-extra's Random.Set, and has the type:

```
set : Int -> Generator comparable -> Generator (Set comparable)
```

you pass it an `n`, a `generator`, and it returns a `generator` of sets of `n` things from your original `generator`. For example:

```
$ fst <| generate (set 5 <| int 0 1000) seed
Set.fromList [286,398,618,961,1000] : Set.Set Int
```

or to answer my original question, of unique pairs on a (eg) 100x100 grid:

```
$ fst <| generate (set 10 <| pair (int 0 100) (int 0 100)) seed
Set.fromList [(2,54),(4,55),(25,50),(35,32),(46,9),(55,9),(62,22),(65,77),(88,74),(95,31)]
: Set.Set ( Int, Int)
```

There is one caveat: The function doesn't know how many unique elements the generator it's given has, so there is the chance that you ask it for 100 unique numbers and give it a dice (`int 1 6`) generator, it get stuck trying to get a 7th unique number forever, leading to a stack overflow probably.

There were two options: crash on the stack overflow, or return bad data, stopping early after a number of strikes.  We chose the second one. If it can't find a unique number 10 times in a row it will just return what it has found so far. I think this is in line with elm's "No runtime errors" philosophy a little more.